# Convert string to decimal format with comma separated

Tags: c#

**Input: 12345678.234
Expected output: 12,345,678.234**

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
    string strRegex = @"(\d+)";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.None);
string arfat = @"12345678.234";

foreach(Match match in myRegex.Matches(arfat))
{
    arfat = arfat.Replace(match.Value, 
                                 string.Format("{0:n}", decimal.Parse(match.Value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any)));            
}
        Console.WriteLine(arfat);
    }
}
```

**Input: 12345678.234
Expected output: 12,345,678.234**

Comment: Even I tried this also not worked string a= "12345678.123";

  string result = Regex.Replace(
    a, 
    "[0-9]+", 
    m => decimal.Parse(m.Value).ToString("n", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
  Console.WriteLine(result);

Comment: Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#NFormatString)